# Bash /shell/ script md5 hash tree output to .csv file

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, md5, md5sum

i need bash /shell/ script to md5sum hash all current directory tree files to one single .csv file like this :

```
"index.php","add95c73ccafa79b4936cf7236a074f4"
"logs/index.html","1c7b413c3fa39d0fed40556d2658ac73"
```

Thank You very much ;)

Comment: You should really *try* something and come back with problems rather than ask people to write code for you.

Comment: Srrry Noufal, but this is my big problem ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can try the command below, but it will only work if:

- There are no `"` characters in your filenames
- There are no newlines in your filenames

If that's OK, then this should work for you:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 md5sum | \
    sed -r 's/^([0-9a-f]{32})  (.*)/"\2","\1"/'
```

Otherwise you'll need to do proper CSV quoting, in which case I'd suggest writing a short Python script to do this, using the [csv](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) module.  For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os, csv, sys, subprocess, hashlib

writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

for directory, subdirectories, filenames in os.walk('.'):
    for filename in filenames:
        h = hashlib.md5()
        full_filename = os.path.join(directory, filename)
        with open(full_filename, 'rb') as f:
            while True:
                data = f.read(8096)
                if len(data) == 0:
                    break
                h.update(data)
        writer.writerow([h.hexdigest(), full_filename])
```

Comment: Thank You Mark, Work Like Charm :)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 md5sum | perl -pe 's/^(.*?)\s+(.*)$/"$2","$1"/'
> md5.csv
```

Comment: yes, work like charm, but output is like this :

Comment: dd5d02cc750d2855cf6f6c5bf5bea587  ./language/index.html

Comment: @EvanPalMcDan: Please try my modified command.

Comment: YeSSS, BiNGo, Thank You Codaddict :)

Comment: One less pipe/cmd if you use `find . -type -f -exec md5sum {} \;`

Comment: @ShawnChin : error : find: Arguments to -type should contain only one letter :(

Comment: sorry, that was a typo. Should be `find . -type f -exec md5sum {} \;`

Comment: THX @ShawnChin ;) workin' great too:)     find . -type f -exec md5sum {} \; | perl -pe 's/^(.*?)\s+(.*)$/"$2","$1"/' > md5.csv

Answer (score 0):

```
md5sum * | awk '{ print "\"" $2 "\",\"" $1 "\"" }'
```

Comment: This would fail if the filename had a space it.

Comment: Thank You! Work with correct output like this but i need it to process through all directories recursively, without this error : md5sum: templ: is directory

"index.php","31fa74772d49e0c661ce8ee28f52b590"

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
perl -pne 's/^"(.*)","([0-9a-f]+)"$/$2 *$1/io' < input | md5sum -c
```

Comment: @EvanPalMcDan: come again? What do you think my solution is on?

Comment: i have no .exe files on tree ;) md5sum.exe: command not found

Comment: arg... cygwin artefact. Just drop the exe of course

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as shown below. Below, I am using the cksum utility which calculates the CRC checksum. You can use your utility which generates the MD5 checksum. You can redirect the output to a .csv file.

```
#!/bin/ksh

for file in $(find $1 -type f)
do
    filename=$(basename $file)
    checksum=$(cksum $file | cut -d " " -f 1)
    echo \"${filename}\",\"${checksum}\"
done
```

Comment: work perfect, but without path of file :(

Comment: If you need the complete file path as well in the output then check the following 

    #!/bin/ksh 
 
    for file in $(find $1 -type f) 
    do 
        checksum=$(cksum $file | cut -d " " -f 1) 
        echo \"${file}\",\"${checksum}\" 
    done